# Tile chart is showing .2 increments not whole days

Tags: c#, wpf, visifire

This code is showing the axis line in .2 increments, which is not so useful as we are showing 
number of days for patients in this group. I can't see anything that would have causes the .2 perhaps you can see something or where else would i locate the error?

```
<Button x:Class="OTFDashboard.Common.Modules.MissedMedications.Views.MedicineTileView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
        xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=WPFVisifire.Charts"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="300"
        d:DesignWidth="300"
        MinHeight="{StaticResource TileMinHeight}"
        MinWidth="{StaticResource TileMinWidth}"
        MaxHeight="{StaticResource TileMaxHeight}"
        MaxWidth="{StaticResource TileMaxWidth}"
        Command="{Binding Command}"
        Template="{StaticResource TileControlTemplate}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Blue">
        <vc:Chart x:Name="MedicineChart"
                  Watermark="False"
                  Width="Auto"
                  Height="Auto"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  MinHeight="200"
                  MinWidth="{StaticResource ChartMinWidth}"
                  CornerRadius="15,15,15,15"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                  FontSize="8"
                  Background="Transparent">
            <vc:Chart.PlotArea>
                <vc:PlotArea Background="#00000000" />
            </vc:Chart.PlotArea>
            <vc:Chart.Titles>
                <vc:Title Text="Number of patients who Missed Medications" />
            </vc:Chart.Titles>
            <vc:Chart.AxesX>
                <vc:Axis IntervalType="Days"
                         ValueFormatString="MMM-d"
                         Interval="1">
                    <vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                        <vc:AxisLabels Angle="0" />
                    </vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                </vc:Axis>
            </vc:Chart.AxesX>
            <vc:Chart.Series>
                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Column"
                               DataSource="{Binding MedicineSource}"
                               XValueFormatString="MMM-d">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="XValue"
                                        Path="Day" />
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="YValue"
                                        Path="Count" />
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using [Microsoft's Chart Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx) here.

Looks like you've set the [`Interval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval.aspx) property correctly. But if you're talking about grid lines you need to use the [`MajorGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.majorgrid.aspx), [`MinorGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minorgrid.aspx) [`MajorTickMark`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.majortickmark.aspx) and [`MinorTickMark`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minortickmark.aspx) properties.

Only other thought I have at the moment is to change your X-axis datatype to a double instead of DateTime and see if that helps.

Most of my knowledge of the charting controls comes from poking around in the [samples code](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart). Perhaps you can find a sample which is close to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

ChartName.Series(seriesName).YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32

From - (Visual Studio 2010 Chart control: Make Y Axis an Integer value, not decimal)